# JDBC implementation: error with regard to parameters

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc, inner-join

I am working on creating a JDBC program that will show a list of grades that a selected student has in their respective classes. However, I keep getting the error "Procedure or function 'getStudentHistory' expects parameter '@studentId', which was not supplied."

Here is my stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[getStudentHistory]

@studentId INT
AS

    SELECT LastName, FirstName, Year, Term, C.Prefix + ' ' + CAST(C.Num AS CHAR(3)) + ' - ' + SEC.Letter AS [Course Number], 
                Units, isNull(G.Letter, ' ') AS Grade
    FROM Student S

 INNER JOIN StudentInSection SIS
    ON S.StudentId = SIS.StudentId
 INNER JOIN Section SEC
    ON SEC.SectionId = SIS.SectionId
 INNER JOIN Course C
    ON C.CourseId = SEC.CourseId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Grade G
    ON G.GradeId = SIS.GradeId
 INNER JOIN Semester SEM
    ON SEM.SemesterId = SEC.SemesterId

    WHERE S.StudentId = @studentId
    Order BY Units DESC
```

Here is my function within my Main Class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void showStudentHistory()
{

    System.out.print("\n Please enter the Id of a current student you wanna see grades for");
    System.out.print("\n==>");

    Scanner insertstudentID = new Scanner(System.in);
    int passedStudentID = insertstudentID.nextInt() ;

    Student student = new Student(passedStudentID, null, null);
    List<Student> students =  student.getStudentHistory(passedStudentID);
    String tabs = "\t\t";
    System.out.println("LastName"+ tabs + "FirstName"+ tabs + "Year"+ tabs + "Term"+ tabs + "Course Number"+ tabs + "Units"+ tabs + "Grade");
    System.out.println("---------"+ tabs + "---------"+ tabs + "--------"+ tabs + "-----------");


//            Student tempStu = students.get(passedStudentID);
//            System.out.println(tempStu.getmStudentId() + "\t\t\t" +
//                    padRight(tempStu.getmFirstName(), 15) + "\t\t" +
//                    padRight(tempStu.getmLastName(), 15) + "\t\t" +
//                    tempStu.getmNum());

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("\nHit Enter to continue...");
    String discard = kb.nextLine();
```

And here is the accompanying function in my Student Class:

```
public List<Student> getStudentHistory(int StudentID) {

       List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
       Connection con = dbConnect();
       PreparedStatement ps = null;
       ResultSet rs = null;
       try {
           ps = con.prepareCall("getStudentHistory");
           rs = ps.executeQuery();
           // Iterate through the data in the result set and load the List
//             while (rs.next()) {
//                 students.add(new Student(rs.getInt("StudentId")
//                         , rs.getString("LastName")
//                         , rs.getString("FirstName")
//                         , rs.getInt("Year")
//                         , rs.getString("Course Number")
//                         , rs.getInt("Units")
//                         , rs.getString("Grade")
//                         )                                                   
//                         );
//             }
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } finally {
           if (rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
           if (ps != null) try { ps.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
           if (con != null) try { con.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
       }
       return students;

}
```

I know that my stored procedure works fine by itself in SQL Server, but I am getting confused with how I can properly implement a stored proc that has inner joins. All of my other stored procedures for creating, updating, deleting, and displaying data work fine, but they only make use of a single Student table. I would appreciate any pointers that the community can give me, and I'd be happy to post more of my code if anyone thinks it would be relevant to finding a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with your use of inner joins. The stored procedure expects a parameter, you haven't provided it. You should call it like:

```
ps = con.prepareCall("{call getStudentHistory(?)}");
ps.setInt(1, studentId);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

See also the documentation of [`CallableStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html).

As a sidenote, I'd advise you to use java naming conventions: variables and parameters start with a lowercase letter, not uppercase (eg use `studentID`, not `StudentID`).

Comment: Thank you, you were right about this fixing the error regarding a missing parameter. My other question is how I can properly output the contents of my table via the java classes.

Comment: @user3274463 I'd suggest you ask a separate, new question for that. You should only ask one question per question.

Comment: If you look in my main class, I have commented out a set of code that I used to output the 4 attributes of the Student class onto the screen. In order to do this, there are get functions that were defined with respect to the constructor. I could redefine my constructor to include additional  values so that I can make get functions for other variables, but that would change the order in which my variables, appear. That would make the rest of my code fail, as it would make other functions call the wrong variables. Any thoughts?

Comment: Thank you, I'll post another question then.